# Pointwise function equality proof

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

Is it possible to prove an equality of functions given they are equal pointwise? - i.e. to build following function:

```
pointwiseEquals: (f: a -> b) -> (g: a -> b) -> ((x: a) -> (f x) = (g x)) -> f = g
```

However, I doubt that it takes place in constructive logic, so maybe at least the following take place?

```
pointwiseEquals': (f: a -> b) -> (g: a -> b) -> ((x: a) -> (f x) = (g x)) -> (f = g -> Void) -> Void
```

Comment: This is kind of orthogonal to constructivism, so both things are not provable.

Comment: This statement is called `funext` and can be postulated without apparent contradictions: `postulate funext : {f, g : a -> b} -> ((x : a) -> f x = g x) -> f = g`